# Trait 'Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable' not found (500 Internal Server Error)

Tags: php, laravel, notifications

Hello I am trying to implement notifications in my project so this error is occuring

Here is my model User.php

```
namespace App\Models;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Laravel\Lumen\Auth\Authorizable;
use \Dusterio\LumenPassport\LumenPassport;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use App\Notifications\ResetPassword as ResetPasswordNotification;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, AuthorizableContract,Notifiable
{
    use HasApiTokens, Authenticatable, Authorizable, HasFactory,Notifiable;
    protected $table = 'www_users';
    protected $primaryKey = 'userid';
    public $incrementing = false;
    protected $fillable = [
        'userid', 'realname'
    ];


    protected $hidden = [
        'password'
    ];

    public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
    {
        $this->notify(new ResetPasswordNotification($token));
    }
}
```

Which is showing error Trait 'Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable' not found (500 Internal Server Error) When I call sendPasswordResetNotification function from controller.

Comment: Does that file exist where your autoloader can find it?

Comment: Try running `composer dumpautoload`

Comment: I installed notifications by command artisan make:notification ResetPassword on server so on server composer is not running

Comment: I don't know about it @  Machavity

Answer (score 0):

You can pull in the notification library used Lumen 8.0:

> "illuminate/notifications": "5.3.*"
> into your `composer.json` then running composer update to pull in the notification libraries.

You will also need to add

> $app->register(Illuminate\Notifications NotificationServiceProvider::class);

to your bootstrap/app.php

Thanks